# Openlayers 6.15.1 icons cut with declutter: false

Tags: openlayers

I use Openlayers 6.15.1 and I need to show a point layer on the map set with `declutter: false` because I don't like that the user has to zoom in to find out that there are more features. However, the outermost icons are cut together with their label. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

icon down =
[image]

icon right =
[image]

icon top-left =
[image]

**I created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/andreaordonselli/pen/OJopBvb)** for convenience but I carry the style and layer code

Style:

```
var size = 0;
var placement = 'point';
var style_Civici = function(feature, resolution){
    var context = {
        feature: feature,
        variables: {}
    };
    var value = ""
    var labelText = "";
    size = 0;
    var labelFont = "13.0px \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif";
    var labelFill = "#e31a1c";
    var bufferColor = "#ffffff";
    var bufferWidth = 3.0;
    var textAlign = "left";
    var offsetX = 8;
    var offsetY = 3;
    var placement = 'point';
    if (feature.get("numcivico") !== null) {
        labelText = String(feature.get("numcivico"));
    }
    var style = [ new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({radius: 4.0 + size,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(35,35,35,1.0)', lineDash: null, lineCap: 'butt', lineJoin: 'miter', width: 0}), fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(227,26,28,0.9490196078431372)'})}),
        text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                              labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                              bufferWidth)
    })];

    return style;
};
```

Layer:

```
var format_Civici = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var features_Civici = format_Civici.readFeatures(json_Civici, 
            {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:25832'});
var jsonSource_Civici = new ol.source.Vector({
                attributions: "<img src='styles/legend/Civici.png' /> <b>Civici</b>"
            });
jsonSource_Civici.addFeatures(features_Civici);
var lyr_Civici = new ol.layer.Vector({
                declutter: false,
                source:jsonSource_Civici, 
                style: style_Civici,
                permalink: "Civici",
                popuplayertitle: "Civici",
                interactive: true,
                title: "<img src='styles/legend/Civici.png' /> Civici"
            });
var extent_Civici = jsonSource_Civici.getExtent();
lyr_Civici.setProperties('extent');
lyr_Civici.set('extent' , extent_Civici);
```

****UPDATE****

I noticed that by deleting the final 3 lines of the Layer, relating to the extent, the problem is solved. How can I keep the layer extent definition but keep the icons from being clipped?

Comment: Which browser and operating system are you using?  I do not see the problem using your Codepen with Chrome on Windows.

Comment: You are right! I understood what happened: just before posting the question, I deleted from the codepen 3 lines related to the extent that I didn't think were necessary for the problem, instead just deleting them solves the problem! How can I keep the layer extent definition but keep the icons from being clipped? Update question and codepen. Thanks

Comment: You only need to set an extent on the layer if you do not want to render features outside that extent.  But you know you have no features to exclude because it is the extent of all the features.  If you were simply setting that property as information for use elsewhere you should avoid using any of the property names listed under "Observable Properties" in the API.

Comment: I define "extent" because in ol-ext's layerswitcher there is a button that zooms to the extent of the layer which only works if the layer's "extent" property is defined. I will ask Viglino if it is possible to define another property. Alternatively: Is it possible to change my extent definition by adding "n" pixels per side? It would be enough to add 10px per side to avoid cutting. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can buffer an extent.  The buffer is defined in projection units so would be your `n` pixels multiplied the the maximum resolution (meters per pixel) you might display it in `ol.extent.buffer(extent, n * maxResolution)`

Comment: I checked the layerswitcher documentation and you can customise what happens when you want to zoom to extent with an `onextent` function, so for vector layers you could use extent calculated from the source `onextent: function(layer) {
  map.getView().fit(layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector ? layer.getSource().getExtent() : layer.getExtent()); 
},`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the help of Mike, whom I will never stop thanking, I understood that the definition of the layer's `extent` cut off objects that it remained outside.
So the hypotheses to solve are 2:

increase the extent using the buffer function, example like this:

```
var extent_Civici = jsonSource_Civici.getExtent();
var buffer_extent_Civici = new ol.extent.buffer(extent_Civici, 50);
lyr_Civici.setProperties('extent');
lyr_Civici.set('extent' , extent_Civici);
```

solve the root problem, since I need the extent definition in the ol-ext layerswitcher, example like this:

```
var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
    ...
    extent: true, //funziona solo definendo extent nei layer
    onextent: function(layer) {   map.getView().fit(layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector ? layer.getSource().getExtent() : layer.getExtent());  },
    ...
    });     
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```